# How to respond to a pool of existing poorly worded questions without creating a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicates

What's the right way to post a self-answered question on a topic which underlies many existing questions?

Consider in particular a case wherein many questions have been posed about Topic X.
These questions are not particularly well written because the askers are not themselves experts in Topic X and so don't really know what they're asking about.
Answers have been given, but for the most part suffer a lack of precision inherited from the relatively aimless nature of the questions themselves.
How does one post a self answered question on Topic X, designed to provide a clear and unifying response to those poorly posed questions, without violating the duplicate rule?

Comment: We have, in the past, closed *older* questions as duplicates of *newer* ones that were better formulated/written/answered/etc. This *could* be one of those cases.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Interesting. I did not know that.

Comment: As a first option, consider to try to improve (some of) the existing poorly worded questions if possible. This might not be possible without ruining the intent of OP's question. Then a new question is in order.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what self answered question were you thinking of posting?

Comment: @JohnRennie: I really want to clear up all of these  questions about quantum measurement, state collapse, and the relationship between interaction/entanglement and measurement. Having dealt with those issues in an intimate lab setting I think I can actually offer a good description which is both enlightening and fairly points out what is known and what is not.

Comment: Similar situation here, regarding why speed of light = $3\times 10...$ http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56973/why-does-the-speed-of-light-c-have-the-value-it-does/212063#212063

Comment: See the chain of possible duplicates.

Answer (score 6):

Exactly what the official SE line is I'm not sure, but I'm personnally not that fussed about duplicates. Apparent duplicates often stress different aspects of a problem, and I'm not sure it does any harm to have separate questions and answers with different perspectives on a problem. I've even occasionally flagged a question as a duplicate of a question that has itself been closed as a duplicate because I thought it had a better answer.

So I would go ahead and write your canonical question and answer. The worst that will happen is that it gets ignored, and the best that it will provide a valuable synthesis of previous related questions.

An example is the issue of wave particle duality. Even though there's a [question specifically devoted to asking what it is](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46237/is-the-wave-particle-duality-a-real-duality) (with 9 answers!), and [numerous other related questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=wave%20particle%20duality), I still don't feel there is a perfect Q/A for the interested amateur. Maybe one day I shall attempt to write one :-)